Run postgres service in gitlab ci
I unsuccessfully try to start Postgres service in Gitlab ci for run my Laravel app. Pg service stopped with error "could not translate host name "'*'", service "5432" to address: Name or service not known". I need add postgres config  "listen_addresses='*'" for avoid "error: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "host.docker.internal" to address: Name or service not known" error. If you have experience in running Postgres service in Gitlab ci environment, please share the solution. Thank you
Gitlab ci error
2024-09-26T11:27:55.574837166Z 2024-09-26 11:27:55.574 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.7 (Debian 14.7-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2024-09-26T11:27:55.575134102Z 2024-09-26 11:27:55.574 UTC [1] LOG:  could not translate host name "'*'", service "5432" to address: Name or service not known
2024-09-26T11:27:55.575138008Z 2024-09-26 11:27:55.574 UTC [1] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "'*'"
2024-09-26T11:27:55.575139402Z 2024-09-26 11:27:55.574 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2024-09-26T11:27:55.575898570Z 2024-09-26 11:27:55.575 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down

gilab-ci.yml
Tests:
  stage: Tests
  rules:
    - when: always
  image:
    name: php:8.3.9
  services:
    - redis
    - name: postgres:14.7
      command: ["postgres", "-c", "listen_addresses='*'"]
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: landlord_test
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    REDIS_HOST: redis
    REDIS_PORT: 6379
  script:
    - curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.4/install.sh | bash
    - source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
    - nvm install 16 && nvm use 16
    - chmod +x ./pipelines-config-build.sh
    - ./pipelines-config-build.sh
    - php artisan passport:keys
    - chmod 660 storage/oauth-private.key storage/oauth-public.key
    - php artisan migrate:fresh --path=database/migrations/landlord --database=landlord --seed
    - php artisan tenants:artisan "migrate:fresh --database=tenant --seed"
#    - ./vendor/bin/pest -d memory_limit=-1 --configuration phpunit.xml tests/ --compact --coverage
    - ./pipelines-e2e-test-frontend.sh

If remove line from gitlab-ci.yml command: ["postgres", "-c", "listen_addresses='*'"], i getting another error could not translate host name "host.docker.internal" to address: Name or service not known

looks like the correct option is "listen_addresses=*" (without an extra  '  quote)
